# How to include native librairies in Play2 project?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In an app, I'm using native librairies (so/dll files). When using play locally, I simply drop the files in the /lib folder what seems to work great.

My problem is on the `play dist` command.Only .jars are included and I have execution errors due to missing native librairies.

How do I include those files in the zip generated by the `play dist` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can easily pack the libraries into the dist-package. I see some workaroauns

1. Rename them dll.jar or so.jar so they would be part of the dist-package.
2. Create your own sbt-task which do the packaging for you.
3. Pack the dll/so in a separate zip together with a special start-script which unpack the dist and copy the dll/so to the correct place.

Sorry this are only workarounds, but I fear there is no clean solution. You can create a ticket for that but I fear you must solve it your selves.

Comment: Ok, no need for a ticket for that. My need seems really specific.